# Run php script as windows 10 services using nssm

Tags: php, nssm

I have a PHP script inside
`c:users\xampp\htdocs\myapp\myphpscript.php`

What I want is to make a windows service that runs this PHP script in the background.
So I searched for some questions here but they were not effective.
Is there anyone who can help me to make a windows service using nssm that executes for my script.

Comment: Q: why not just use Windows Task scheduler, and call your script directly?

Comment: You need to do the [appropriate amount of research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and make some attempts yourself first. If you get stuck on something specific along the way, post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and explain where you're stuck. You should also read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We can help if you get stuck with your implementation, but this question is currently way too unfocused and broad.

Comment: You are right , i will share my code and what i jave still done.

Comment: STRONG SUGGESTION: forget about nssm; forget about the complexity of writing a true "Windows Service".  Just invoke your PHP script from Windows Task Scheduler (or, alternatively, launch it from Windows Startup).  Extra credit bonus points: consider using PowerShell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a batch file with following content and put it in windows startup ;)

start /b path-to-php-installation\php c:\users\xampp\htdocs\myapp\myphpscript.php

Comment: Thanks @paulsm4 it was much needed repo to comment on post lol :D

Comment: it works well , but can i make to repeat automatically every 4 hours in day

Comment: add the batch file to task scheduler to run every 4 hours